# lodash shorthand function not working properly

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to delete an element from a string array by using lodash's `remove` shorthand function, but it removes all the elements from the array.

```
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Then I try to remove one element with

```
var num = 'two';
_.remove(arr, num);
```

but it removes all the elements. It works fine when I use a callback function like

```
_.remove(arr, function(o){
    return o === num
});
```

Can anybody help me to figure this out?

Comment: Second arg for `.remove` is a predicate that returns truthy value and in JS `"two"` is truthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var num = 'two';   
_.pull(arr, num);
```

`_.pull` is probably what you're looking for. That function will remove elements from an array using the second argument (list or single value) as a filter. It both mutates the array and returns a new array.

[Relevant lodash doc](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pull)